# Mysql how to create an if statement within a having to find out if my variable is in between two other values

Tags: mysql, if-statement, having

I'm trying to create a stored procedure like followed

...Having (IF(input_val between 1 and 10, 1,0) AS rank

example

```
|input_val  | rank  |
--------------------|
| 1         | 1     |
| 11        | 0     |
| 3         | 1     |
| 22        | 0     |
| 4         | 1     |
| 5         | 1     |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A HAVING clause normally follows a GROUP BY clause and is used to test the results of an aggregate function. I don't think that's appropriate for what you want here. How about:

```
...
CASE WHEN input_val BETWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS rank
```